# Setting cookie with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, subdomain

I'm trying to set a cookie with javascript and this is what I have so far.

```
    function Set_Cookie( name, value, expires, path, domain, secure )
{
// set time, it's in milliseconds
var today = new Date();
today.setTime( today.getTime() );

/*
if the expires variable is set, make the correct
expires time, the current script below will set
it for x number of days, to make it for hours,
delete * 24, for minutes, delete * 60 * 24
*/
if ( expires )
{
expires = expires * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
}
var expires_date = new Date( today.getTime() + (expires) );

document.cookie = name + "=" +escape( value ) +
( ( expires ) ? ";expires=" + expires_date.toGMTString() : "" ) +
( ( path ) ? ";path=" + path : "" ) +
( ( domain ) ? ";domain=" + domain : "" ) +
( ( secure ) ? ";secure" : "" );
}
```

And calling the above method to set  a cookie as

```
Set_Cookie( "IsLoggedIn", "true", 15, "/", ".spodemo.com", "secure" );
```

That gave me strange problem. Working in FireFox, Internet Explorer as well and **not working in chrome.**

Any help or suggestion with this ?

Thanks.

Comment: can you use jQuery? or do you need to stick with raw js?

Comment: @AnthonyShaw Yes. I cannot use Jquery. Otherwise I would go for it.

Comment: Is any error displayed in the console?

Comment: @Pazza22 No errors Pazza. I'm clueless.

Comment: What happens if expires is 0? It seems to be setting to now.

Comment: @Pazza22 But i'm passing  15 in my parameters , as you can see.

Answer (score 2):

I've used this in the past for raw js cookie setting

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Referenced from http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: Thanks Anthony , and May I know why the existing code not working for chrome alone. ? where as I'm able to see the cookie in Firefox and IE.

Comment: not sure, I can duplicate your issue in Chrome through Firebug, began to think it had something to do with the date format, but they're both the same. I would have to look into it further. I solely posted what I posted, because I have used it cross-browser without any issues. You could also easily add your secure and domain parameters that are omitted from these methods

Comment: Other than that date format anything else you can see ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you test it in another pc? Also, change your JQuery Version. I had same problem, it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You dont change domain and secure. Without them work OK, viz. below.

```
function Set_Cookie( name, value, expires, path )
{
  // set time, it's in milliseconds
  var today = new Date();
  today.setTime( today.getTime() );

  /*
  if the expires variable is set, make the correct
  expires time, the current script below will set
  it for x number of days, to make it for hours,
  delete * 24, for minutes, delete * 60 * 24
  */
  if ( expires )
  {
    expires = expires * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  }
  var expires_date = new Date( today.getTime() + (expires) );
  document.cookie = name + "=" +escape( value ) +
  ( ( expires ) ? "; expires=" + expires_date.toGMTString() : "" ) +
  ( ( path ) ? "; path=" + path : "" );
}
```

Comment: No, I need to set domain. Is there any problem with that ?

Comment: That is security reason. As I set or get cookies with other domain, I kill whole internet.

Comment: :) but I have a relationship of parent child relationship between domains and they both deployed on same server.

Comment: That no one cares, how to ensure that they have the same owner? Free hosting have thousand sub domains e.g. one.freehosting.com, two.freehosting.com etc. and each has a different owner.

Comment: Have you heard about cross domain ?

Comment: As StackExchange, StackOverflow, Unix&Linux and one login?

Comment: Mate, you have to do on the server side.

Browser can not do it.